# HTML form automatically tries to validate and doesn't wait for the submit button to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML form:

```
<form onclick="return validateForm();">
<h1 style="color:whitesmoke;">Register</h1>
<h2>Please enter your details:</h2>
<br />

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" />


<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<br />

<input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First name" />

<input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Last name" />

<br />
<div style="position:relative; top:10px;">
    <label>Birth Date: <input type="date" id="birthday" name="DateOfBirth"></label>
</div>
<br />

<input type="number" placeholder="Age" min="10" max="120" name="age" style="width:15%;" />

<br />
<label style="position:relative; right:20px; top: 10px;">
    Gender: <input id="setD_male" type="radio" name="gender" checked>
    <label for="setD_male">Male</label>
    <input id="setD_female" type="radio" name="gender">
    <label for="setD_female">Female</label>
</label>
<br />
<div style="position:relative; top:10px;">
    <input id="checkmark" type="checkbox" /><label> I agree to the terms and regulations.</label>
</div>


</div>
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="error" value="">
<button type="submit" id="Register" name="Register" class="submit-button">Register</button>
</form>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkmark");
var button = document.getElementById("Register");
button.disabled = true;

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
  button.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
});
function validateForm() {
  var error;
  var email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;
  if (!email.endsWith(".com")) {
    alert("Email has to end with '.com'");
    return false;
  }
  var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
  var FirstName = document.getElementsByName("FirstName")[0].value;
  var LastName = document.getElementsByName("LastName")[0].value;
  var DateOfBirth = document.getElementsByName("DateOfBirth")[0].value;
  var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
  var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender")[0].value;
  if (
    email === "" ||
    password === "" ||
    FirstName === "" ||
    LastName === "" ||
    DateOfBirth === "" ||
    age === "" ||
    gender === "" ||
    email === null ||
    password === null ||
    FirstName === null ||
    LastName === null ||
    DateOfBirth === null ||
    age === null ||
    gender === null
  ) {
    error = "nullRegistration";
    window.location.href = "systemMessagesjsp.jsp?error=" + error;
    return false;
  }
  if (
    !Register(emailAddress, password, firstName, lastName, DOB, age, gender)
  ) {
    error = "CantCreateUser";
    window.location.href = "systemMessagesjsp.jsp?error=" + error;
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("successfully signed in");
    return true;
  }
}
```

When I debug it, I can see that upon entering this page on my browser, the function "validateForm()" is being called, and also called again when I click the submit button. Why is it being called upon entering ?

I tried debugging it and I could see that upon entering the page, it jumps straight into validateForm and does all of the code inside of it, where instead, it should only perform the code inside of it if the user hits the submit button at the bottom of the page. I guess it registers the button from the previous stage as the submit button for some reason.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is also happening is that the browser validates your form as well (using the `min="10"`, `max="120"` attributes for example). Instead implement checking min/max ranges in your submit handler then the browser won't run its own validation.

Comment: I deleted the min & max values from the html page and put it in the script. I still get sent to validateForm() when I enter the page. Any idea why ?
This is my first time using a jsp, so I don't really understand if this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the submit event instead of the click event on the form.

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Comment: I tried it before and now again. Unfortunately it still enters validateForm() as soon as I hit the button in the previous page to transfer me to this page.

Comment: @YonatanVizel that is not what I'm seeing when using the code you've given us: https://jsfiddle.net/0es4zuby/1/.  This answer is correct; you definitely don't want to be using the onlick event on the form element.   If your validate function is being called immediately on page load, you must have other code not shown in the question that's calling it.

Comment: This is the full code in it's entirety.
I'm not sure why it happens.
https://jsfiddle.net/VizelJ/u0vmwgt2/1/

Also, I have some java classes that register users to a text file on my laptop. Is there a way to include these classes in my jsp file and use their objects and functions ?
I honestly can't get it to work.

Comment: Obviously I'm new to this whole subject. I'm even not sure I'm commenting on the right place right now, but I honestly can't understand what's wrong with the code I sent. I may not fully understand how jsp works and why it runs validateForm() upon entering, but I need some helpful answers. I understand that this is an HTML problem. What is the problem then ? I changed the min & max age to be in the script instead of html. What else should I do ? I can't seem to advance and I'm stuck.